# html::tagparser not working

Tags: html, perl, parsing

```
my $url  = "\'http://".$server.":4080/cgi-bin/gen_graph.pl?view=5&SUBSYS=\'";
my $html = HTML::TagParser->new( $url );
my @list = $html->getElementsByTagName( "pre" );
print $list[0];
foreach my $elem ( @list ) {
        if($elem->innerText =~ /APIs/){
                my $text = $elem->innerText;
                if ( $text eq "" ) {
                } else {
                        @API_list = split(/\s+/, $text);
                        print $API_list[1];
                }
        }
}
return \@API_list;
}
```

here the line

```
my @list = $html->getElementsByTagName( "pre" );
```

not working. if i do this as a seperate script it is working well.. but if i include it in another script there is no value in @list. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting an error message?  If so, what is it?

Have you thought to check the return value of `HTML::TagParser->new()`?  If it's failing, it may be doing so silently, and you only find out later when you try to use your `$html` object.

I do think the URL you're handing to it looks odd.

```
"\'http://".$server.":4080/cgi-bin/gen_graph.pl?view=5&SUBSYS=\'"
```

Why the two layers of quotes?  (double quotes, and then escaped single quotes).  Wouldn't this work:

```
my $url =      'http://' 
          .    $server 
          .    ':4080/cgi-bin-gen_graph.pl?view=5&SUBSYS=';
```

(Extra whitespace added to make it easier to read the concatenation operator.)

Comment: Ya thank you. it is where the problem is.. i thought as single quote will be a problem and made it with two layers... i got it now...